# How can i minimize the source code theft in visual studio 2010/TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

how can i limit the redistribution of source code on different machines. I want that the source code should not compile/build within visual studio /TFS if it is redistributed to some other machine with different visual studio license?

If there is no built in mechanism i need some direction. perhaps i need to install an add in for visual studio that will check on compile time if it is not installed it will simple not allow the code to compile?

Comment: There is nothing out-of-the-box to achieve this and I doubt anything 3rd party exists either.  Even if you could stop the solution from building, there would be nothing to stop someone copying and pasting the source into a new solution.

Comment: Note: Visual Studio 2010 drops out of support this month (July 2015)

Comment: What is your concern here? Why are you looking to achieve this?

Comment: I want to prevent / minimize any possible source code theft. For example i don't want someone to steel the source code from my organization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store all of your developer infrastructure (developer workstations, TFS infrastructure, etc) in an isolated building. This building should have no internet access whatsoever.

Post security guards outside the building. Armed is preferable, but not strictly necessary.

Each person entering the building should be stopped by the security guards and forced to surrender all personal effects (cell phones, cameras, tape recorders, thumb drives, etc). Nothing should be allowed to come into this room or exit the room. This includes things like eyeglasses and clothing, since they could have covert recording devices embedded in them.

All people entering or exiting the room are thoroughly searched, both upon entry and exit from the room. Ideally they would be cavity searched and x-rayed, although finding security guards comfortable with performing cavity searches could be challenging, and they would almost certainly command a higher salary.

This will prevent your employees from:

- emailing code to themselves
- taking pictures of the code on their screen
- writing code down on sheets of paper
- dictating the code into a recording device
- copying code to a thumb drive and smuggling it out of the room

Of course, this doesn't account for the possibility that an employee has an eidetic memory. If that's the case and you find out, you'll have no choice but to have them killed upon their departure from the company.

*Please note that the 'having former employees killed' portion is satire. I do not actually recommend having people killed. That is illegal and immoral.*

Comment: Loved the aim for a possible answer (:

Answer (score 2):

Do not allow people to access your source code if you don't want them to steal it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this out of the box and no known third party tooling for this.