# IP restriction for Visual Studio Team Services which is connected to Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-devops

We've recently connected our Visual Studio Team Services account to Azure Active Directory. The problem is Team Services is available to our users from everywhere and anyone can login and download the full source code of a project.

Is there anyway so we can limit access Azure AD users login based on their IP address so this way we could protect our source repository?

In general how can we deny Azure AD login requests from the outside of our organisation?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i minimize the source code theft in visual studio 2010/TFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377318/how-can-i-minimize-the-source-code-theft-in-visual-studio-2010-tfs)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the IP address white-list from Azure side, refer to this link for details: [Enhancing Azure MFA with Contextual IP Address Whitelisting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ad/2014/04/25/enhancing-azure-mfa-with-contextual-ip-address-whitelisting/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went through the steps but I couldn't see the Whitelisting feature. It just shows [Suspend multi-factor authentication for remembered devices]